# How to split a string in to list where the number of string in the list is defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

So if I have a string:

```
s = "this is just a sample string"
```

I want to obtain a list of 3 characters each:

```
l = ["thi", "s i", "s j", "ust", " a ", ...]
```

Comment: plenty of ways to do this. with regex you can do `re.findall(".{,3}", string)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `list` for a variable name because it's a keyword in Python. Here's how you can do it:

```
string =  "this is just a sample string"
l = [string[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(string),3)]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['thi', 's i', 's j', 'ust', ' a ', 'sam', 'ple', ' st', 'rin', 'g']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `list comprehension`

```py
string = "this is just a sample string"
n = 3
[string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(string), n)]
```

output

```
chunks = ['thi', 's i', 's j', 'ust', ' a ', 'sam', 'ple', ' st', 'rin', 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

With [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```py
from more_itertools import chunked
list = [''.join(chunk) for chunk in chunked(string, 3)]
```

Comment: It's honestly overkill to import a package for something like that

Comment: @Xiidref I am proposing this as an alternative solution to built-in slicing. It's also an invitation to look into other features of more-itertools, which is a very handy package in other use cases. That said, downvote as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can match 1-3 characters using the dot to match any character including a space and a quantifier `{1,3}`

```
import re

print(re.findall(r".{1,3}", "this is just a sample string"))
```

Output

```
['thi', 's i', 's j', 'ust', ' a ', 'sam', 'ple', ' st', 'rin', 'g']
```

If you don't want the single char match for `'g'` then you can use `.{3}` instead of `{1,3}`

Answer (score 0):

Using generators to split the string in fixed-size blocks. If the length of the string is not a multiple of the block's size then the "tail" it will be also be added (no information provided). If "tail" not desired check if `len(string) % block_size == 0`: if `False` then `output[:-1]`.

```
import itertools as it

s = "this is just a sample string"

s = it.tee(s, 1)[0] # as generator, or just iter(s)!
out = []
for block in iter(lambda: ''.join(it.islice(s, 0, 3, None)), ''):
    out.append(block)

print(out)
```

or with a `while` loop

```
import itertools as it

s = "this is just a sample string"

s_iter = iter(lambda: ''.join(it.islice(s, 0, 3, None)), '')
out = []
v = is_over = next(s_iter, False)
while is_over is not False:
    out.append(v)
    v = is_over = next(s_iter, False)

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
s = "this is just a sample string"
length =  3
lst = []
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    lst.append(s[i:i+length])
    i+=length
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['thi', 's i', 's j', 'ust', ' a ', 'sam', 'ple', ' st', 'rin', 'g']
```